# How to remove space from UINavigationbar between Button

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

How to remove this space [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGROg.png). Here is my code :

```
UIButton *postButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[postButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"post_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
postButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44);
[postButton addTarget:self.viewDeckController action:@selector(postAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:postButton];
```

thx for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As standard, you can't. And the cost of doing so is likely to be prohibitive as you would need to create your own custom navigation bar (or subclass) and manage the drawing yourself.

That said, the gap is there for a reason as touch detection isn't so accurate near the edge of the screen and fingers are big...

Answer (score 0):

First there is no need to use `UIButton` but we can. you can use it `UIBarButtonItem`

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"post_btn.png"];
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:myImage style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(postAction:)];  
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;    
[button release];
```

Answer (score -1):

As standard, you can't. but you can set manually.

1- setNavigationBarHidden hidden.

```
    [self.navigationItem setNavigationBarHidden:TRUE];
```

2- Take one UIImageView  size = 320 X 45. //as per your required height

3- set your button on it. make it height smaller then above image.